# Is it possible to combine :%s/ \= and | in vim?

Tags: vim

The following is roughly what I am trying to do in vim

```
:let g:ID = 1
:%s/^/\= g:ID | let g:ID = g:ID * 1.2/
```

Now, it looks like vim disregrads everything after the bar 
(that is the `let g:ID = g:ID * 1.2` part.

I could of course write a function that multiplies g:ID
with 1.2 and returns g:ID's value, but I'd like to 
forego this.

Thanks
Rene

*edit* for clarity:

In vim-script, I can write multiple statements on *one* line if I use the bar (|) to chain them. So, instead of

```
let g:ID = 20
let g:ID = g:ID * 1.2
let g:ID = g:ID * 1.2
```

I could also write

```
  let g:ID = 20 | let g:ID = g:ID * 1.2 | let g:ID = g:ID * 1.2
```

Now, the **\=** thingy allows me to substitute a regular expression with a vim script expression. For example, I could do a

```
:%s/ABC/\=line(".")/
```

which would replace every occurence of ABC in my current buffer with the line number on which it is found.

Similarly a

```
:%s/^/\=g:ID/
```

would write the current value of g:ID at the beginning of each line in my buffer.

That's all fine and dandy, but I'd like to have more than one expression in the replacement part and was wondering if I could achieve that by chaining such expressions with the bar. In my case, I'd like to manipulate g:ID after every substitution call,
hence

```
:let g:ID=20
:s/^/\=g:ID|let g:ID=g:ID * 1.2/
```

would result in writing 20 at the beginning of the first line in my buffer, 24 at the beginning of the second line in my buffer, 28.8 at the beginning of the third line in my buffer and so on.

I hope I made myself clearer now.

Comment: it is not instantly obvious what you want to achieve ...

Comment: I want to chain two "commands" in the replacement part of a search-repacle pattern match.

Comment: obviously i wasnt clear about what _i_ was trying to say: edit your question so it becomes clearer without the comments :)

Comment: Only expressions are allowed after `\=`. Or exactly one expression. `|` is command delimiter, and if you need to use `let` you either need a function (e.g. if you would need to use it in `s/RE/\=EXPRESSION/g`) or `:g` as @peth suggested. Is this a vim golf question? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:global` as its command is executed for every line.

```
:let g:ID = 1
:g//s//\=g:ID/ | let g:ID = g:ID + 1
```

If you want to constrain the replacement, either limit by the `:global` pattern, or prefix `:global` with a range, or both.

```
:10,20g/foo/s/^/\=g:ID/ | let g:ID = g:ID + 1
```

That should prepend the incremented `g:ID` for every line that matches `foo` from line 10 to 20 (inclusive).

Comment: Thank you. Although I hoped there would be a "more direct" way, your answer comes closest to what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to define a function:

```
function! Accu(varname, mult)
  let old = {a:varname}
  let {a:varname} = {a:varname} * a:mult
  return old
endfunction
```

and use it this way:

```
:let g:ID = 1
:%s/^/\=Accu('g:ID', 1.2)/
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it is possible with a function. But sometimes I feel it's just not worth writing the function... that is, if I could go without...

Answer (score 0):

Try `<bar>` instead of `|`
Have a look at: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Best_Vim_Tips

Comment: <bar> instead of | results in E15: invalid expression : g:ID <bar> let g:ID = ...  and a E121: undefined variable bar